# How to pass the result of an Asynchronous function as a deffered object

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

i'm trying to get my head around working with  Deffered objects especially in cases where you have to perform multiple asynchronous operations on every item in an array. In the code below i just want to be able to access the result of an asynchronous array after it is complete, in my case it is the results array.

- To explain the code below

  1. **ListData** function derives the source data which is an array that i intend to manipulate.
  2. **getPictureComplete1** perfroms an async operation (**ListDataWithPicture**) on every item in the array above
  3. The idea of step 2 was to add an image url to every item in the array from Step 1 and then use the new array as an input to step 4
  4. could be to print the images to the page or perform additional manipulations on the array

```js
var mydeferred = $.Deferred();
var ListData = function (){    
    listName = 'TeamInfo';
       $.ajax({
             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select=Name/Title,Name/Name,Name/Id,Name/EMail,Name/WorkPhone&$expand=Name/Id",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: onQuerySucceded,
            error: onQueryFailed
        });
        return mydeferred.promise();
    }
var ListDataWithPicture = function(userId, callback) {
        // execute AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$filter=Id eq " + userId + "&$select=Picture",
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("Starting async operation for " + userId);
                    var pictureLink = "";
                    var mydata = callback(data.d.results[0].Picture.Url);                    
                    return mydata
                },
            error: onQueryFailed
            });            
                   
    }
    
function onQuerySucceded (data){
    var PeopleCompleteList = [];
    for (i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++) {
                    //check if the user exists if he does store the following properties name,title,workphone,email
                    if(data.d.results[i]['Name'] != null){
                        personName = data.d.results[i]['Name'].Name.split('|')[2];
                        userName = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Name'];
                        UserTitle = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Title'];
                        UserphoneNumber = data.d.results[i]['Name']['WorkPhone'];
                        UserEmail = data.d.results[i]['Name']['EMail'];
                        Id = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Id'];
                        PeopleCompleteList.push(PersonConstructor(personName, UserTitle, UserphoneNumber,UserEmail,Id));
                    } 
                }
    mydeferred.resolve(PeopleCompleteList);
}
 
function getPictureComplete1 (data){
            var def = new $.Deferred();
            var results = [];
            var expecting = data.length;
            data.forEach(function(entry, index) {
                //this is the asynchronous function
                ListDataWithPicture(entry.UserId, function(result) {
                    results[index] = {imageUrl: result, UserId: entry.UserId, name: entry.name, Title: entry.Title, phoneNumber: entry.phoneNumber, Email: entry.Email};
                    //console.log(result);
                    if (--expecting === 0) {
                    // Done!
                    console.log("Results:", results); //this works succeffully from here 
                    def.resolve();
                    return results
                    //mydeferred.resolve(results);
                }
                });

            });
            return mydeferred.promise(); 
}


$(function () {
       ListData().then(function(data){
           //how can i access the results array in this function after it has completed??          
           var value = getPictureComplete1 (data);
           //the line below results undefined,which i understand because the getPictureComplete1 function may not have completed at the time
           console.log(value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is an asynchronous operation, the only time that you have access to the array of results from your `ajax` call in `LineData` is within the scope of the `onQuerySucceded` function that you assigned to the `success` property in your `ajax` configuration. The function you define here will be fired after a successful response was received.

When establishing a deferred promise, you will need to define what data resolves the promise. Whatever you pass into the `resolve` method will be available as a parameter within a subsequent then block on your promise chain.

I'm not seeing `onQuerySucceded` defined in your example, but it would look something like this:

```
var ListData = function (){
   var mydeferred = $.Deferred();
   listName = 'TeamInfo';
   $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select=Name/Title,Name/Name,Name/Id,Name/EMail,Name/WorkPhone&$expand=Name/Id",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function onQuerySuccess(data) {
           mydeferred.resolve(data);
        },
        error: onQueryFailed
    });
    return mydeferred.promise();
}
```

Now, after a successful call, the promise will resolve with the data. So, something like this is possible:

```
ListData()
   .then(function (data) {
      // do something with the data
   })
```

Similarly, you will want to define what are the rejection cases for your deferred promise. For example, maybe the ajax call doesn't succeed. For this, you will want to use the `reject` method on the `deferred` object.

For example:

```
var ListData = function (){    
   var mydeferred = $.Deferred();
   listName = 'TeamInfo';
   $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select=Name/Title,Name/Name,Name/Id,Name/EMail,Name/WorkPhone&$expand=Name/Id",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function onQuerySuccess(data) {
           mydeferred.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function onQueryFailed(error) {
           mydeferred.reject(error);
        }
    });
    return mydeferred.promise();
}
```

This works similarly to resolve, but will resolve to any subsequent `catch` or `fail` blocks. So, something like this will work

```
LineData()
    .then(function (data) {
        // it was successful, do something with the data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // There was an error. The then block was not called.
        // Do something with the error.
    })
```

Put even more simply, you can set `mydeferred.resolve` and `mydeferred.reject` as these properties directly. Like so:

```
var ListData = function (){    
   var mydeferred = $.Deferred();
   listName = 'TeamInfo';
   $.ajax({
      url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select=Name/Title,Name/Name,Name/Id,Name/EMail,Name/WorkPhone&$expand=Name/Id",
      type: "GET",
      headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
      success: mydeferred.resolve,
      error: mydeferred.reject
   });
   return mydeferred.promise();
}
```

You will want to do something similar with your `ListDataWithPicture` function so that it also returns a promise with the data that you need:

```
var ListDataWithPicture = function(userId, callback) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$filter=Id eq " + userId + "&$select=Picture",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data.d.results[0].Picture.Url)
        },
        error: deferred.reject
    });            
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

This allows you to do something like this:

```
LineData()
    .then(function (data) {
        // performing on just the first result:
        return ListDataWithPicture(data[0]);
    })
    .then(function (url) {
        // do something with the result
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // do something with the error
    });
```

Because you want to perform a aynchronous operation on each of the items in your array, I'd recommend to use `Promise.all` which executes and resolves an array of promises.

```
LineData()
    .then(function (data) {
        // create a map of promises
        var promises = data.map(function (item) {
            return ListDataWithPicture(item);
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then(function (urls) {
        // urls will be an array of urls resolved from calling 
        // ListDataWithPicture on each item in the array resolved
        // from above
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // do something with the error
    });
```

Here are some good resources to learn more:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: thanks Erik, the ListData() function works okay, i can access the deferred object, where i am struggling with is the next ".then()" where i have to run the async function(ListDataWithPicture) for each item in the object that was passed..`if (--expecting === 0) {// Done!
console.log("Results:", results); //this works succeffully from here                    
}` there is a point in the code where i can say async operation on each item is completed but i dont know how to then establish a deferred object which i can then pass to the next .then().

Comment: I just updated my answer above that should solve this. You want to use Promise.all to perform an asynchronous function on an array of items. The results of that will be available in your next then assuming that you are returning the promise.